# Why is Rack (Rails) converting these form post data into two separate Hash objects?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, rack, url-parameters

I'm having a 'mare just now trying to build a complex HTML form using Rails. Since the form is more complex than usual, I'm not using `form_for` for the tricky inputs.

Here's the part I'm having trouble with:

```
- users.each do |user|

    .checkbox
      = hidden_field_tag "booking[events][][id]", event.id
      = hidden_field_tag "booking[events][][delegates][][id]", user.id

      = label_tag "booking[events][][delegates][][attending]", for: id_for_event_bookings_checkbox(user, event) do

        = check_box_tag "booking[events][][delegates][][attending]", 1, value_for_event_booking_checkbox(f.object, user, event), id: id_for_event_bookings_checkbox(user, event)
        = user.name
```

FYI:

id_for_event_bookings_checkbox # => "booking_form__checkbox_#{user.id}_#{event.id}"

value_for_event_booking_checkbox # => true/false

When I post this form, the params are malformed.

What I get:

```
{"booking"=> {"booker_id"=>"36", "events"=>[{"id"=>"2", "delegates"=>[{"id"=>"35", "attending"=>"1"}]}, {"id"=>"2", "delegates"=>[{"id"=>"36"}]}]}}
```

What I need:

```
{"booking"=> {"booker_id"=>"36", "events"=>[{"id"=>"2", "delegates"=>[{"id"=>"35", "attending"=>"1"}, {"id"=>"36"}]}]}}
```

I presume I need to change the structure of `the check_box_tag`s `name` but I have no idea what to structure them as.

**NOTE**: I'm stuck using this more verbose structure because Rails's *StrongParams* suck.

Answer (score 0):

In this case try using
[`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) instead of fighting Rails.

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
end

class Event
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :delegates
end
```

Using form_for and fields_for to generate your fields is actually pretty simple:

```
= form_for(@booking) do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :booker_id
  = f.fields_for :events do |ef|
    = ef.fields_for :delegates do |df|
      = df.label :attending do 
        = df.check_box :attending
      # assumes the delegate is a user
      = df.object.name
```

Note that this will not give you the exact desired params but will instead give 
you params that work with the conventions of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

```
{
  booking: {
    events_attributes: {
      0 => {
        id: 6
        delegates_attributes: {
          0 => {
            id: 6
            attending: 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can whitelist the params by:

```
ea = [:id, { delegates_attributes: [:id, :attending] } ]
params.require(:booking)
  .permit(:booker_id, events_attibutes: ea)
```

Comment: If delegate is some kind of join model between users and events you can use the ActiveSupport [`delegate`] method (http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) or just `df.object.user.name `

Comment: Accepts nested attributes for wasn't a viable solution for this problem—the form was too complex. But thanks :)

Comment: I would say the root cause is probably poor architecture. You're trying to do far to much in a single action. Or you're not doing it at the right level.